# Which package to use for displaying custom tables/information in R

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization

Currently I am working on a project to create a Shiny app that displays something similar to the following:
[image]

The interactive part of Shiny and the underlying data cleaning code is done. What I need help with is **finding a package for customizing the table**.
Strictly speaking it is a table, with one observation (the name of which is not included) with 15 variables displayed in a grid pattern. The name of the variable is referenced as "Info x" on the picture and the value is the red x or green check. (In my actual work, each variable has 3 different levels, and they should be displayed with either some custom graphic (that I would also need a package for) or text). In Shiny the output should be a picture, that can also be downloaded (just like a plot).

Answer (score 0):

Try the GT package -->
https://gt.rstudio.com/

or you can use kable --> https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html

I have used both, but maybe GT would be better suited for your case